# size of inner elements of cells

Tags: matlab, size, cell-array

I'm reading some data with their attribute (say A in which first row is ids and second row is their attribute value) . I'd like to place such data in a cell where the first column are the unique ids and second row their attribute. whenever there's duplicate values for the attribute, I'll put on the vacancy available on front of its row. for example I'd like to construct C

```
A =
 1     2     3     2
 2     4     5     9

C{1}=
1   2   0
2   4   9
3   5   0
```

when I'm going to test the size of inner homes in cell, e.g.

```
size(C{1},2)

ans = 3

size(C{1},1)

ans = 3

size(C{1}(1,:),2)

ans =  3
```

All return 3 since it occupies empty homes with 0. So how should I understand where to put my new data (e.g. (1,5))? Should I traverse or find the place of 0 and insert there?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Using `find(C{1}(j,:) == 0,1)` should indeed work for the jth row, but be aware that if the entire row is filled, find will return an empty array of indices. [But why not use matlabs map container filled with lists](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html)?

Comment: So, first i've to check if it contains 0s or not using ismember or find to find the first index of non-zero element and if it returned empty I use the end+1 to insert new items. I've to use this many times in my code.. What 's the main benefit of map container with list? cell doesnt do the same thing?

Comment: @hamideh You don't have to do it each time. You could do this in a single go. I have posted an answer. check it out :)

Comment: @Santhan, thank you so much, it exactly works, just will you please tell me what those `.` dots means in your script? and also my case in fact has 3 row and I'd like to place those value in order to the result cell. e.g.  A=[ 1 2 3 2;2 4 5 9;1 2 7 4] and I'd like C be in the format of cell with output [1]->[2 1]`, [2]->[4 2; 9 5], [3]->[5 7]` So, is your script changable to general case of adding columns under identifier row? (attributes of duplicate identifier get followed by each other or each get placed in one row)

Comment: If you are asking `.'`, it just means transpose. while using `'` does conjugate transpose. of course using them for real numbers produces same results. I don't understand your second question

Comment: @SanthanThanks for your quidance. For the second question, I said what happens to your solution if there are more than two rows in our first example and we would like to place them in cell in a way that if there are duplicate (as in the case of 2) they are added sequentially. i.e. output of this matrix?  A=[ 1 2 3 2;2 4 5 9;1 2 7 4] . if not clear, i'll post it later in a separate thread so inputs and outputs can be clearly placed. Thanks for spending time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a cell-Array for these kind of problem? How did you generate your `C` matrix?

Even though you have used cell-Arrays for `C` matrix, each element of `C` is a matrix in your case, so that the dimensions should be constant.

I have used a cell array inside a matrix. (i.e) each elements takes its own size based on the duplicate sizes. for eg, you could see that `C{2,2}` has *two* values while `C{1,2}` and `C{3,2}` has *only one* values. you could easily check the size of them without checking for zeros. Note that, even if any values were zero, this code will still work.

The first column of the matrix represents `identifiers` while the second column represents the `values` which takes its own size based on the number of duplicates.

Here is my Implementation using [`accumarray`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and [`unique`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to generate `C` as a cell-array.

**Code:**

```
C = [num2cell(unique(A(1,:).')),  accumarray(A(1,:).',A(2,:).',[],@(x) {x.'})]
```

**Your Sample Input:**

```
A = [1     2     3     2;
     2     4     5     9];
```

**Output:**

```
>> C

C = 

[1]    [         2]
[2]    [1x2 double]
[3]    [         5]

>> size(C{2,2},2)

ans =

 2

>> size(C{1,2},2)

ans =

 1
```

From the **[DOC](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)**

> **Note:** If the subscripts in subs are not sorted with respect to their linear indices, then `accumarray` might not always preserve the order of the data in `val` when it passes them to `fun`. In the unusual case that `fun` requires that its input values be in the same order as they appear in `val`, sort the indices in subs with respect to the linear indices of the output.

---

**Another Example:**
**Input:**

```
A = [1  2   1   2   3   1;
     2  4   5   9   4   8];
```

**Output:**

```
C = 

[1]    [1x3 double]
[2]    [1x2 double]
[3]    [         4]
```

---

Hope this helps!!

Comment: further, for the general case of two dimensional cell array. e.g. `a` which at the end is a 3*3 cell `a = [2x1 double] [2x1 double] [2x1 double] ; [ 1] [2x1 double] [] ; [ 1] [] []` Now for the number of rows in first column we can use size(a,1) but how can we determine the number of non-empty cells in second column for example (which is 2)?

Comment: @hamideh `sum(~cellfun(@isempty, A))` this will give the number of non-empty cells for each column

Comment: @hamideh Glad it worked :) if your problem is solved, consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: As you see, since I dont know the size of my final cell array, and rows and column are added incrementally, I'm confronted with empty cells . If i want to avoid these empty cells, you mention to use nested cell. is it a common practice? isn't it much more complicated? is it better from memory perspective? thank you so much for granting me your precious experience..

Comment: @hamideh Its very fine to use nested cell arrays.. creating empty cells and removing them is costly.. should avoid them whenever possible